# Moving workflows to new version in AWS SWF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

Is there a way to move workflows from one version to another in AWS SWF ? Some workflows are waiting to be triggered. The timer has already started. I'm looking to seamlessly move them to new version of the workflow.

Comment: This is not really an answer - but we simply aren't using versioning, we just make sure there are no breaking changes for open workflows (for example, code changes that support both the old and new formats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in SWF. Workflow once started maintains the same version until closed. [ContinueAsNew](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ContinueAsNewWorkflowExecutionDecisionAttributes.html) allows overriding the version, so it is possible to "update" a workflow by calling ContinueAsNew.

BTW: [Cadence](https://github.com/uber/cadence) (open source version of SWF) supports [inline versioning](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/workflow/Workflow.java#L996) of the workflow code which allows changes to already running workflows.